# Induced electric field direction

Tags: electric-fields

Is the magnitude and direction of the induced electric field affected by the external magnetic field or only by the internal magnetic field?

[image: External B exists]

[image: only internal B exists]

If the internal B changes in both cases are exactly the same, is the magnitude or direction of the induced electric field the same at point P?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. Certain spatial gradients of the electric field at any given point are related to the rate of change of the magnetic field *exactly at that same point*. To be precise, the relationship is
$$
\mbox{curl } {\bf E} = - \frac{d {\bf B}}{d t} .
$$
In case you are not familiar with curl: the quantity on the left is a combination of gradients of electric field components in different directions.

If we integrate the above equation over a finite area $A$, we get
$$
\oint_p {\bf E} \cdot d{\bf l} = - \frac{d \phi}{dt}   \tag{1}
$$
where $p$ is the path around the boundary of the area and $\phi$ is the flux
$$
\phi = \int_A {\bf B} \cdot d{\bf S}  \tag{2}
$$
This integral is over the area A.
The integral of the electric field around the loop (left hand side of equation (1)) is the quantity called 'e.m.f.'. So now you have Faraday's law.

Now I am guessing that for the question what you really want to know is the e.m.f. If that is what you want to know, then you can use equations (1) and (2) and on the right hand side the magnetic field that appears is *the field inside the loop*. The field outside does not contribute to this integral.

Note, this does not necessarily imply the field outside has no effect on $\bf E$ itself. Rather, it has no effect on the integral of $\bf E$ around the loop.